# send audio blob file in input file and send form but i have problem with laravel request

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm having difficulty loading an audio blob into an input file, then sending it to the Laravel controller and saving it in the db, is there a nice way to do this? I ask for your help, thank you very much in advance...
This is my code..
blade

```
<form action="{{ route('salva.qrcode.audio') }}" method="POST"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
       @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
   <div>
   <label>Fai un vocale</label>
      <br>
   <h2>Recorder App</h2>
    <p>
    <input type="button" id="record" value="Registra" />
     <input type="button" id="stopRecord" disabled value="Stop" />
   </p>
   <audio id="recordedAudio"></audio>
   <input id="fileInputElement" name="audio" type="file" accept="audio/*" required />
   </p>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
   @foreach ($result as $item)
   @if (empty($item->audio))
 @else
    <audio controls>
  <source src="/audio/audio/{{ $item->audio }}">
 </audio>
@endif
 <input type="text" name="id_qrcode" value="{{ $item->id }}"
  hidden />
 @endforeach
 </div>
 <div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-tertiary">Salva Audio</button>
</div>
</form>
```

javascript

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
})
    .then(stream => {
        handlerFunction(stream)
    })

function handlerFunction(stream) {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive") {
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
                type: 'audio/mp3'
            });
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            recordedAudio.controls = true;
            recordedAudio.autoplay = true;
            let file = new File ([blob], "audio.mp3", { type: "audio/mp3", lastModified: new Date().getTime() });
            let container = new DataTransfer();
            container.items.add(file);
            fileInputElement.files = container.files;
            fileInputElement.value = container.files;
            sendData(blob)
         }
    }
}

function sendData(data) { }
record.onclick = e => {
    record.disabled = true;
    record.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    stopRecord.disabled = false;
    audioChunks = [];
    rec.start();
}
stopRecord.onclick = e => {
    record.disabled = false;
    stop.disabled = true;
    record.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    rec.stop();
}
```

controller laravel

```
 /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updateAudio(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id_qrcode;

        // Audio

        $request->validate([
            'audio' => 'required|file|mimes:m4a,mp4,mp3,mpeg,mpga,wav,aac'
        ]);

        $audioName = time() . '.' . $request->audio->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->audio->move(public_path('audio/audio'), $audioName);

        Colori::where('id', $id)->update(['audio' => $audioName]);

        $result = Colori::where('id', $id)->get();

        return $this->indexClienti($request)->withErrors(['msgSuccess' => "Audio aggiunto con successo"])->with(['result' => $result]);
    }
```

I have tried many methods even in creating a new blob function, but nothing to do, I ask for your help with patience

Comment: I solved it, guys if anyone could need the extension with which it generates the file is .ogg so in the back of the controller just insert ogg in the mimes thanks everyone